# block elements around floated elements with background color

Tags: css, css-float

This is my case:

http://jsfiddle.net/vZ4sB/

Is there a way that the H1 background color ocupies the whole width of the container MINUS the floated element width?

Comment: If it works, it might be best to just give .floater{ background:#FFF; } to cover the H1 background. http://jsfiddle.net/vZ4sB/1/  If you need a transparent background your float, then a different solution would be needed.  Floating the H1 will not expand the width to fill the container.  You would need to set specific widths as commonly done when making CSS grid columns.

Comment: The problem is that is not "blue" what i want to use as background, but an image. So this would require offset the image. And the .floater might not have the same width every time...

Comment: +1 for `.floater` class name. It might not have the same meaning in Germany.

Comment: What will be in `.floater` and `h1` exactly? Your comment above is confusing me.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=floater

Comment: @Nicosunshine Kerching!!! Obviously I wasn't refering to the first definition :)

Comment: @MyHeadHurts: Pun intended ;)

Comment: What im trying is to put a mask over the h1 with a background color, to give it a irregular shape, like highlighted with a marker. Like this: http://www.watchyourweb.de/

Comment: Ah ok - and that will mess with the background image thanks to the margin collapse. I have seen this type of question asked before and there doesn't seem to be a definitve solution. If you know the width of the background image can you not just `float` the header tag left and apply the width?

Comment: @Dbugger You're trying to put a mask over the H1 like the purple highlights on that German website?  For example, like the "WILLKOMMEN BIE WATCH YOUR WEB!" title or the "WELCHER WEBTYP BIS DU?" titles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsFiddle is temporarily down, but here's what I worked out:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>
    <img src="my_img.jpg" />
    <span>Here's my header!</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}

h1 {
  background: url(my_header_bg.jpg) top right no-repeat;
  height: 30px;
}

h1 img {
  float: left;
}

h1 span {
  background: url(my_header_bg.jpg) top left no-repeat;
  float: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

I'm shooting a little bit in the dark here, but I'm guessing you have a header with some text, a background image behind the text, and perhaps a logo to the left? Please let me know if I'm wrong.

This might need a little more tinkering, but what I did was float both the image and span (with text) in the H1 and set the height on the h1 to a static height. This way the span will always butt up against the image and the H1 will extend 100%. I set a left-aligned background image to the span. Then I set a right-aligned background image to the H1. If the background image is a seamless pattern of some sort, this will probably work. If it's an image with a static width, you can set the span to the width of the background image and fade it out to the H1.

If it's just blue, you can just keep the H1 background blue.

See if this fits what you're working with.

Comment: What if I dont know the width of the H1, because I dont know the width of the image?

Comment: Sorry I missed that in your original post. Let me fix :)

Answer (score 0):

You could, if the width of the `.floater` element is static at 200px (plus 2px for borders) use an adjacent sibling selector to assign a `margin-left` to those `h2` elements following a `.floater`:

```
.floater + h1 {
    margin-left: 202px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vZ4sB/7/).

Comment: I think you mean H1 instead of H2 right? I think this is a reasonable solution except that I find sibling selectors to be somewhat restrictive in that they rely on the markup to always be in that specific order, which might become difficult to maintain down the line. I think a more flexible approach is independent selectors that don't have dependencies on the markup order.

Comment: @Dbugger also states in his second comment that "the `.floater` might not have the same width each time"

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
h1 {
    background: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question.  Reread the question and clarify your answer.